# Expanding ListView Groups

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor, expandablelistadapter

In my `ExpandableListView`, I require all groups to be expanded by default.

I am using a `CursorTreeAdapter` and have overidden `changeCursor` to perform the following behaviour:

```
  @Override
  public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    super.changeCursor(cursor);
    int groupCount = getGroupCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
      if (!getListView().isGroupExpanded(i)) {
        getListView().expandGroup(i, false);
      }
    }
  }
```

The entire for loop takes under 10ms to execute, however if I am scrolling while a call is made to `changeCursor`, with new elements added in, the UI freezes for much longer.

The other solution I tried was expanding the group as a user scrolled to it (on `newGroupView` or `bindGroupView`) however that causes very jerky scrolling.

How can I have a `ListView` with headers that is populated by a `Cursor` that is able to scroll smoothly?

Comment: Try to expand the group in the `getGroupView` method.

Comment: @G.T. Same issue as having it in newGroupView and bindGroupView as getGroupView just calls into those anyways

Comment: I think one way is store group position into cursor. It help avoid loop.

Comment: @fisher3421 Not quite sure what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: @nyx You can call Cursor.getPosition() into newGroupView and expand group by this position

Comment: @fisher3421 As I mentioned in my post, I did try doing that as well and it caused jerky scrolling

Comment: @nyx I thought that you use loop by all elements into newGroupView

Comment: @fisher3421 I tried two solutions, one was the loop in changeCursor, the other was using Cursor.getPosition() in newGroupView. Perhaps I'm not understanding you clearly?